# How to put a static bar between StatusBar and React-Navigation Header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation. Based on the attached image, I tried to put the static bar at the parent level:

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <StaticBar/>
     <Navigation />
   </View>
</Provider>
```

but it ended up covering the StatusBar. And I know how to put the static bar below the header. But how can I put a static bar between StatusBar and React-Navigation Header ?

Thank you!

[image]